# laravel 5.2 return int from mysql only

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Laravel 5.2 returns int value from any form field in MySQL. For example, I have a big number in varchar format 6271403119 this method:

```
static public function gawUser($userid = null, $filed = 'id')
{
    if (Empty($userid)) $userid = Auth::user()->id;
    $user = Gaw_user::where('user_id', $userid)->first();

    if (!empty($user)) return $user->$filed;
    else return false;
    }
}
```

return 2147483647

Comment: Your code has an extra curly closing bracket...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `Gaw_user` model has incrementing disabled, otherwise eloquent will assume your id is an auto incrementing integer.

```
class Gaw_user extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;


    ...
}
```